# How to fix my maximum output and how to add how many maximum and minimum number

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, max, min

So here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float average;
    int i, n, sum = 0, num, min, max;

    printf("Number of Students: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    max = min = num;

    for (i = 1; i < (n + 1); i++) {
        printf("Students no: %d\n", i);
        printf("Score: ");
        scanf("%d", &num);

        if (num > max) {
            max = num;
        }

        if (num < min) {
            min = num;
        }

        sum = sum + num;
    }

    average = 1.0*sum/n;

    printf("Average score is %.2f\n", average);
    printf("The highest score is %d\n", max);
    printf("The lowest score is %d\n", min);

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is my maximum output is always wrong and I don't know my mistake. And how do you add how many student who got maximum and minimum score?

Comment: "_my maximum output is always wrong_" Why? What is the right output? What do you get instead? Your other question seems unrelated, and a thread should only contain 1 question.

Comment: Nowhere have you initialised `min` and `max`. The line: `max = min = num;` should perhaps be: `max = 0; min = MAXINT`.

Comment: so the maximum output that I get are wrong ( for example when I input 100,88, and 89, it shows that the minimum is 88, the average is 92.33, and the max is 4195504, which is wrong)

Comment: well, after I change max = min = num to max = min = 0, my lowest number somehow always become 0

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Comment: OT: regarding: `scanf("%d", &n);`  always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  Note:  the `scanf()` family of functions return the number of successful `input format conversion specifiers` (or EOF)  in the current case: any returned value other than 1 indicates an error occurred.

Comment: in general, when handling min and max calculations, initialize `max` to INT_MIN and initialize `min` to INT_MAX which are exposed via: `#include <limits.h>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement

```
max = min = num;
```

does not make sense because the variable `num` is not initialized.

What you mean is the following. I suppose that a score can not be a negative number.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned int n;

    printf( "Number of Students: " );
    scanf( "%u", &n );

    unsigned int min = 0, max = 0, count_min = 0, count_max = 0;
    unsigned int sum = 0;

    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) 
    {
        printf("Students no: %u\n", i + 1 );
        printf("Score: ");

        unsigned int num;
        scanf( "%u", &num );

        sum += num;

        if ( i == 0 || max < num ) 
        {
            max = num;
            count_max = 1;
        }
        else if ( !( num < max ) )
        {
            ++count_max;
        }

        if ( i == 0 || num < min ) 
        {
            min = num;
            count_min = 1;
        }
        else if ( !( min < num ) )
        {
            ++count_min;
        }
    }

    float average = n == 0 ? 0.0f : ( float )sum / n;

    printf( "Average score is %3.1f\n", average );
    printf( "The highest score is %u that is had by %u student(s)\n", max, count_max );
    printf( "The lowest score is %u that is had by %u student(s)\n", min, count_min );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Number of Students: 6
Students no: 1
Score: 1
Students no: 2
Score: 4
Students no: 3
Score: 3
Students no: 4
Score: 2
Students no: 5
Score: 1
Students no: 6
Score: 3
Average score is 2.3
The highest score is 4 that is had by 1 student(s)
The lowest score is 1 that is had by 2 student(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

On this line here

```
max = min = num;
```

You set all these values to be the same. But `num` hasn't been initialized, so this is undefined behavior. Anything can happen then - it is likely that the program will just proceed with rubbish values for the three variables. Instead, remove this line and initialize your variables like this:

```
int i, n, sum = 0, num = 0, min = INT_MAX, max = INT_MIN;
```

`min` can be set to the highest valid input. Generally you can just set it to `INT_MAX` from `<limits.h>` to set it to the biggest possible value. Likewise for `max` and `INT_MIN`.